# Powershell download file onedrive/googledrive

Tags: powershell

I want to download a file to a pc from onedrive/google drive.

After some digging into this subject i found invoke-Webrequest was the best command to use in this subject.

```
# Download the file $zipFile = "https://xxxxxxmy.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfRW5c" Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $zipFile -OutFile "c:\temp\xxxxxx.exe"
```

only to found out the code was working but only downloaded a .exe file of 156kB
This file i wanted to download is 22mb? i get no error's in powershell but maybe you have any idea what is going on?

zipfiles work but then i need to extract a zip file in the code and i dont know the working code for that..? ( expand-archive didnt work).

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the correct file using that url? For a zip file of 22Mb you need to use [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) or similar. There is plenty code to find on how to use that.

Answer (score 1):

&download=1 needs to be added.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So there is no login context for the session spawned by your script.  If you open one drive in your browser, once authentication is established and a session exists, the browser is given access to the file.

If you open your file that is  156kb in notepad, you should find it's just a webpage saying the URL is not available.

I believe this will help the situation, but it's more complex:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/onedrive-for-business/how-to-download-root-level-files-from-onedrive-using-powershell/m-p/758689

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the link I was using didn't have access to the file directly. When you add in the OneDrive/Google Docs :download=1 it will skip the "virus scan".

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. Note that my fix will only work for Personal one drives and not One Drive for business (Corporate one drive).

1. Upload the file to one drive (personal)
2. Share it so anyone with link can access the file
3. Download the file, pause the download, right click on paused download and do "Copy Download Link" . (i did it with Internet download manager)
4. Paste that link in the script below

```
$DownloadURL = "%PasteDownloadLinkHere"
$FilePath = "Path\To\File\file.exe"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $DownloadURL -OutFile $MSIFilePath
```